# How to dynamically change the number of steps in stepper in flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

I am making a validation form in a stepper format in *flutter*. Each step has a validation form.

When first opening the page, there is only one step.  I want the user to click continue and get one more stepper (i.e Step 2 and get one more step by clicking continue in step 2.)

I have tried to change the number of steps by adding one more step to the list and updating when `changeCurrentStepContinue` is called, but it can't increase the number of steps showing error. On going back and again going forward, I get the updated list.

So how can I change the number of steps on the same page by clicking continue in each step?

Comment: "showing error" then please add the error to your question. Also add the code that demonstrates what you tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how "good" my trick is, but I just change the Key of the Stepper by adding the total amount of items in the list I'm binding to.

```
return Stepper(
      key: Key("mysuperkey-" +  items.length.toString()),
      ...
);
```

This should create a new Stepper when the total of step changes.

Cheers

Comment: This seems to be the quick and easiest solution. Did you by any chance find out if there is any performance imapct?

Comment: I have no idea, but I stopped using it and did one more myself. It started to be a nuisance more than a goodie. 
Love flutter just because if you don't like a component, it takes minutes to do one for yourself.

My recommendation is that you should not hack it, and just build one from scratch.

Comment: @JuanCarlos please can you hint how you built it?

Comment: @cdaiga just change the key dynamically as per the code on my post.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible as per comment in [stepper.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0d707f3897706182a4616393f7262bfe70c73fde/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart#L151) that says `/// The length of [steps] must not change.` but I'd made some edits that works fine for vertical stepper.

Follow this steps to apply that patch into your flutter code

1. `cd` to `flutter` directory
2. download this file [0001-Made-Stepper-Stepper-Size-Dynamic.patch](https://gist.github.com/sanket143/bf20a16775095e0be33b8a8156c34cb9) and keep it in `flutter` folder
3. In your terminal `$ git apply 0001-Made-Stepper-Stepper-Size-Dynamic.patch`

OR

Replace `_buildVertical()` in `/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart` with [this](https://gist.github.com/sanket143/d370910b25498b0a8dfd496bc0749db8) function

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. But instead of manipulating the official code, is that possible to create a custom pub package or class for dynamic stepper? If you create one, I will definitely put it to my dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, It is just a small thing and should not require a pub package. I like the idea of creating a pub package for the same with more customization options then currently we have. I have made a [pull request] (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23381) in official flutter repo. If it gets merged, the problem is solved. Review my PR to increase chances to get merged.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the PR.